# Add Model manually to Entity Framework context InMemoryTest ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, entity-framework-core, xunit

I built a generic repository which will be used as a NuGet Package that receives a context in the constructor.
I want to test the repository InMemory. The problem is that the context exists on another solution and when I try to build fake options, the models inside the context will be null because I am using only the default context.

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "test")
                .Options;
var context = new DbContext(options);
var sut = new Repository<TestEntity>(context);
sut.Add(new TestEntity());
```

I am getting an exception says:

> The entity type 'TestEntity' was not found. Ensure that the entity
>   type has been added to the model.

I have tried to add the model manually to the options:

```
var builder = new ModelBuilder(new ConventionSet());
builder.Entity<TestEntity>();
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext>()
                .UseModel(builder.Model)
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "test")
                .Options;
```

but now it throws when the Add method is being called:

> One or more errors occurred. (Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.)

Anyone knows how to add a model to EF manually? I didn't find something similar to it on the internet.
Thanks

Comment: This is not gonna work. If you want to unit test the repository, create test specific db context, i.e. the way you have created `TestEntity`, now create `TestDbContext : DbContext` containing it.

Comment: Himmm, good idea! I will try it now. Thanks

Comment: It works! Thanks!